# Как узнать что приложение было убито Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-service

Нужно в тот момент когда приложения закрыли, вызвать метод Close() который покажет Toast. onTaskRemoved не работает в Oreo, можно ли как-то обойти это?

Comment: По идее сделать такое просто невозможно (исполнить код в 100% случаев прибития приложения). По крайней мере так в документации написано: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#onTerminate()

Comment: В методе onDestroy() вызови службу, вот из нее и показывай свой тост.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
 // Override методов интерфейса Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
}
```

и в onDestroy() напиши свой код close()